# How do I get all elements of a certain category, type and familiy in revit

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I have a function where I would like to get all elements belonging to a certain category, type and family. I have their names as strings and would like to obtain the actual elements that meet the criteria.

I have tried a bit with the following:

```
    internal static void getElemetWithId(Document doc,string catName, string famname, string symbname)
    {

        Category category=null;
        foreach (var cat in  doc.Settings.Categories){
            if (((Category)cat).Name.Contains(catName))
            {
                category = (Category)cat;
                break;
            }
        }
        HashSet<Element> elements = new HashSet<Element>();
        elements.AddRange(GetFilteredElementCollector(doc, new ElementRetrievalOptions())
          .OfCategory(category).WhereElementIsElementType(famname).ToElements());
            }
```

However this doesn't work as OfCategory does not accept a Category as a argument (it does work for a builtInCategory) and WhereElementIsElementType does not seem to accept any argument.

A possible input for this function would be `document, "Doors" , "M_Single-Flush" , "0915 x 2134mm"`

Comment: Note this is a question that is mostly going to require a knowledge of the revit api rather then c#, also this has to work for revit 2014-2017.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the Revit SDK, http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=16777469, and go through some of the sample code.  You can also look at Jeremy's page: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com, and Harry's page: https://boostyourbim.wordpress.com for more sample code.

You should use the FilteredElementCollector Class to find all the Elements you'd be looking for:

```
FilteredElementCollector allInstances = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(FamilyInstance)‌​).Where(q => (q as FamilyInstance).Symbol.Name == symbname);
```

Comment: To find all the placed instances of a specific FamilySymbol:
`FilteredElementCollector allInstances = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(FamilyInstance)).Where(q => q.Symbol.Name == symbname);`

Comment: Anthony provides the complete and perfect answer above combined with his subsequent comment. +1 from me. Anthony, can you edit your original answer to include the suggestion from the comment in the main text? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the elements belonging to the certain category using FilteredElementCollector class. Pass the name of the certain family name in the query and you will get all the elements of required family and type. I have tried this on Revit 2019 recently.

```
List<Element> listOfElements = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(FamilySymbol)).WhereElementIsElementType()
                .ToElements().Where(e => e.Name == elementName).ToList<Element>();

        ElementId symbolId = listOfElements[0].Id;

        FamilyInstanceFilter familyInstanceFilter= new FamilyInstanceFilter(doc, symbolId);
        IList<Element> familyInstances = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).WherePasses(familyInstanceFilter).ToElements();
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as it allows the filteredelementcollector to be expanded with an ElementIntersectsSolidFilter() for example. I'd extend the first line with a .FirstOrDefault() though to replace line 4